# Laravel 5.2: Eloquent Mutator Not Saving Value on Create

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, mutators

So, I'm simply trying to hash a password on user creation, using an Eloquent mutator. It works perfectly if I update the attribute and save it, but on `create()` it isn't saved - the `password` column is empty.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
}
```

Why does this happen? Do I need to set all mutated columns individually to make them save?

Thanks for your help.

---

### Update

I tried saving the password individually, and that didn't work either. For some reason, the value is getting lost somewhere.

---

### Update 2

I tried separating the hashing from saving the value to the attribute and dd()'d it out. It's hashed properly, but it still doesn't save when the registration form is submitted.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){

    $newPass = Hash::make($password);
    $this->attributes['password'] = $newPass;
}
```

---

### Update 3

I commented out the mutator, and the password is still not being saved. At this point I know the value is being sent to the controller and that the model has access to it. For some reason however, it just isn't saved. Everything else is saved just fine, but not the password.

I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet where you're trying to save or update?

Comment: Are you sure the input field is named properly?
Try to dd() the password and see if the functions is called

Comment: @btl I tried, but apparently my code isn't accepted as code >___>

Comment: @Maky you mean in the controller? `return dd($input['password']);`?

Comment: Oh, and yes it was working fine until I added the mutator. The passwords were being saved in plaintext before, so I needed to hash them to make `Auth::attempt()` work.

Comment: just try dd($password);
Also maybe you need  \Hash::make($password) insted of Hash::make($password)

Comment: @Maky It just returns the plaintext string, as expected.

Comment: And I've added the Hash facade like so `use Hash;` in my Eloquent model, so it should work fine each time. I mean, if I update the password attribute using artisan tinker, it is saved, and the password is also hashed as I want it to.

Comment: Okay, so apparently I'd protected the `password` attribute, so of course it wouldn't save on create. I still don't get why I couldn't directly fill inn the attribute with `$user->password = $password`, but at least it's working now. I hope it doesn't matter from a security point of view though.